# 404 error despite 'location = /url' directive in nginx.conf

Tags: nginx

Short version of the question:

I have this in my `nginx.conf` and the PHP script is set to accept and understand what is needed from it, however, when i go to `/sitemap.txt` i get a 404 error stating "The requested resource /sitemap.txt was not found on this server."

```
location = /sitemap.txt { rewrite /.*$ /index.php; }
```

Longer version:

My complete `nginx.conf` is:

```
worker_processes  1;

error_log       /home/logs/nginx_error.log error;
pid         /home/tmp/nginx.pid;

events
{
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http
{
    client_max_body_size    19M;
    client_body_temp_path   /home/tmp;
    proxy_temp_path     /home/tmp;
    fastcgi_temp_path   /home/tmp;
    uwsgi_temp_path     /home/tmp;
    scgi_temp_path      /home/tmp;
    
    access_log      /home/logs/nginx_access.log;
    
    include mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    port_in_redirect on;
    
    sendfile    on;
    
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    
    server {
        listen      8000;
        server_name www.MYSERVER.COM;
        
        charset utf-8;
        
        location =/
        {
            absolute_redirect on;
            port_in_redirect on;
            server_name_in_redirect on;
            return 301 http://www.MYSERVER.COM:80/home;
        }
        location =/index.php
        {
            default_type text/html;
            
            proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:9000$request_uri;
            proxy_redirect  off;
            include     proxy_params;
        }
        location /uploads/
        {
            root /home/public;
            try_files $uri =404;
            expires 30d;
        }
        location /
        {
            rewrite ^/(?<pagename>.*)$ /index.php;
        }
        location = /sitemap.txt { rewrite /.*$ /index.php; }
        
        location /classes/ { deny all; }
        location /config/ { deny all; }
        
        #allow specific files
        location = /styles.css { root /home/public/resources; }
        location = /script.js { root /home/public/resources; }
        location = /robots.txt { root /home/public/resources; }
        location = /sitemap.xml { root /home/public/resources; }
        location = /favicon.webp { root /home/public/resources; }
        
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   /usr/local/www/nginx-dist;
        }
    }

}
```

I actually do not think that i even need `location = /sitemap.txt { rewrite /.*$ /index.php; }` in there, because `location /` directive should already do the trick, but i wanted to be absolutely sure.

I am positive that the directive runs. If i put something like `return 403;` there, that same code is sent to the browser.

I do understand that it is possible to just make it a static file, but i wanted to automate a process

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i have fond the problem, and will post here in hopes that somebody will find it useful. The problem was that although Nginx was doing everything correctly, it was PHP that has decided to play unfairly and started parsing extensions inside the URL.

The simplest solution for me was to change to

```
location =/sitemap.txt { proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9000/sitemaptext; }
```

and then just add a rule in my PHP scripts that accepted that URL rather than the correct one. It doesn't really matter all that much, since the outside world is non-the-wiser, they still see '.txt' in the address.

I do wish that there'd be a way to do this without such hacks.